# Why is the ARM CMSIS I2C reading function not working?

Tags: c, arm, stm32, gpio, i2c

So I started learning ARM-CMSIS and now I am here at learning the I2C Protocol.
So From some tutorials and guides I now have my code like this:

This is my read function:

```
uint8_t I2C_read(I2C_TypeDef *I2C, uint8_t addr, uint8_t reg) {
    uint8_t data;
    uint32_t temp;
    I2C->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_ACK;
    I2C->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_START;
    while (!(I2C->SR1 & I2C_SR1_SB));
    I2C->DR = addr;
    while (!(I2C->SR1 & I2C_SR1_ADDR));
    temp = I2C->SR2;
    I2C->DR = reg;
    I2C->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_START;
    while(!(I2C->SR1 & I2C_SR1_SB));
    I2C->DR = (addr | 1);
    while(!(I2C->SR1 & I2C_SR1_ADDR));
    temp = I2C->SR2;
    while(!(I2C->SR1 & I2C_SR1_RXNE));
    I2C->CR1 &= ~I2C_CR1_ACK;
    I2C->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_STOP;
    data = I2C->DR;
    printMSG("data: %d\r\n", data);
    return data;
}
```

Write function:

```
void I2C_write(I2C_TypeDef *I2C, uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg, uint8_t data) {
    uint32_t temp;

    I2C->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_START;                  // Generate Start condition

    while(!(I2C->SR1 & I2C_FLAG_SB));           // Wait until the Start condition is sent
    printMSG("Write Test1\r\n");
    I2C->DR = dev_addr;                         // Send device over to the Date register
    while(!(I2C->SR1 & I2C_SR1_ADDR));          // Wait until a Slave responds to the address
    temp = I2C->SR2;
    printMSG("Write Test2\r\n");

    I2C->DR = reg;                              // Send internal register to write to
    while (!(I2C->SR1 & I2C_SR1_TXE));          // Wait until the Transmit register is empty and thus the data is transmitted
    printMSG("Write Test3\r\n");

    I2C->DR = data;                             // Put in the data you want to write to the address
    while (!(I2C->SR1 & I2C_SR1_TXE));
    printMSG("Write Test4\r\n");

    I2C->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_STOP;
}
```

And this is my I2C initialization function:

```
void I2C1_init(void) {
    GPIO_InitTypeDef gpio_init;
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_I2C1EN;
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPBEN | RCC_APB2ENR_AFIOEN;
    gpio_init.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_OD;
    gpio_init.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7 | GPIO_Pin_8 | GPIO_Pin_9;
    gpio_init.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    //GPIOB->ODR |= (1<<6) | (1<<7) | (1<<8) | (1<<9);
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &gpio_init);
    I2C1->CR2 |= 36;
    I2C1->CCR |= 180;
    I2C1->TRISE |= 37;

    I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_ACK;
    // stretch mode enabled by default
    // 7-bit addressing mode enabled by default
    I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_PE;

}
```

It reads the data once and then just stops and I think is stuck in one of the while loops.
(Did not check which one)

I followed the documentation of the STM32F103C8T6, I have a STM32F103C8T6 BluePill board.

With the integrated CMSIS functions it does work :D

Comment: what does it look like on the scope, please post scope plots...

Comment: Im Still a starter so I don't have a scope, sorry. Still looking vor a Starter one :D

Comment: then trying to use the i2c controller in a chip is going to be rough, i2c and spi in general need a scope.  if you bit bang them then you can often get away without it but trying to use controllers that you dont have a lot of experience and intimacy with, is hit or miss.

Comment: (and CMSIS tries to generalize things and make it all harder to program)

Comment: did you create these from scratch or are they part of a library from st and you cant get them to work or something else?

Comment: I created them myself by reading the docs on the Chip. 
It works, but only one time
I will try to figure out which while-loop is causing the problem

Comment: I'm new at this stuff, too, Offhand, a couple of things pop out at me: you call I2C->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_START; twice, which I think is wrong. Also, what are you using for the address? If the device addr is, say, 0x04, then you need to set I2C->DR = addr<<1 + 1; for a read. Take a look at https://github.com/blippy/rpi/blob/master/stm32/bare/i2c.c

Comment: Actually I did manage to do it now, and you actually need to call the Start condition twice.
The First time you just tell the address and the register where you want to read from.
And then you generate the start condition to read the data.

the addr<<1 is done before the function.